# Change <frameset> scrolling with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11, frameset

We are using frames in our application. In one frame the scrolling is set to `"auto"`. I'm trying to change that frame attribute based on a small condition. Here is the HTML and JavaScript:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=5">
    </head>
    <frameset>
        <frame src="#" name="contentFR" id="contentFR" scrolling="Auto" noresize marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    </frameset>
    <script language="javascript">
        var iFrm = document.getElementById("contentFR");
        iFrm.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
    </script>
</html>
```

I'm using IE 11, But my application can only run in IE 5 compatibility mode.

Comment: Do you have a typo in your code above; there shouldn't be a space between `getElementById` and `(`. Also, what is it doing that you aren't expecting; does the attribute not change? If you alert `iFrm.getAttribute("scrolling")` afterwards, what do you see?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. In my code there is no space.

Comment: When you say "my application can only run in IE 5 compat mode," are you saying that is your *target* document mode, or is that presently the only one it works in? Do you want this to work in modern versions of IE, or very old versions?

Comment: Probably relate to the JavaScript not being able to access the element because it isn't loaded yet.  Order of frames loading is undefined so you can't know that the frame is loaded when the JavaScript attempts to run.

Comment: @daylight The JavaScript comes after the element, which means the element has already been created. The JavaScript is targeting the `<frame>` element, and not its document contents.

Comment: Here's a fiddle that shows that the iFrm element is null after the JS runs.
https://jsfiddle.net/L5cLau9f/

Comment: @Sampson: at present my application works only with Document mode 5. Even if i using IE 11, I need to set the document mode to 5 to run my application.

Comment: @fabulous But which browser(s) are you targeting? Are your wanting your site opened in an older document mode?

Comment: @Sampson: Yes, I want to open my site in older document Mode coz, it works properly only in older document modes

Comment: @fabulous Side issue, but why not fix it so that it works in modern browsers? Internet Explorer is on its way out... Windows 10 ships with Microsoft Edge, which won't revert into the older document mode.

Comment: May I ask another obvious question; why not just change the markup?

Answer (score 3):

Updated Approach: Simply clone the node.

```js
// Proceed when the document has loaded
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    // The document has loaded
    if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
        // Stop checking document load-state
        clearInterval( timer );
        // Get our frame, and create a clone of it
        var frame = document.getElementById("contentFR");
        var clone = frame.cloneNode(true);
        // Update the scrolling on the clone
        clone.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
        // Replace original frame with clone frame
        frame.parentElement.replaceChild(clone, frame);
    }
}, 10);
```

See below for deeper explanation of why this route was chosen.

---

I am baffled that changing the property, and/or the attribute, doesn't work. Granted, I can only check from Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10 so I don't know that the same issue would repro in earlier builds of Internet Explorer. Since you said your users will be in Internet Explorer 11, we can safely assume that if we run into the issue, so too will they.

I also found that placing the `<script>` below the frameset wouldn't work either, so I had to place it in the `<head>` (Scripts can only be placed within a `<body>` or a `<head>`, and since there is no `<body>` in this document, we can only place them in the `<head>`). Because the head is parsed/created first, our frame element won't exist in time to change it from the head. Additionally, since we're working with the IE 5 Document Mode, we can't merely listen on the `document` for the *DOMContentLoaded* event.  Instead, I chose to check the `document.readyState` value every 10ms until it registered as *complete*.

Lastly, as you have found, simply updating the attribute doesn't appear to work. Setting the property also doesn't appear to work. Oddly enough, both of these actually change the value from *Auto* to *No* if you inspect the element after performing the operation, but the change isn't reflected in the document. For this reason, I decided to create a brand new frame, replacing the other.

This code feels really, really misguided. Hopefully somebody will come along and share an approach that doesn't require going through such extremes as fundamentally duplicating an element, and applying the attributes of one to the other. Until then, this solution appears to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=5">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Proceed when the document has loaded
            var timer = setInterval(function () {
                if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
                    // Stop checking document load-state
                    clearInterval( timer );
                    // Get our frame, and create a replacement
                    var frame = document.getElementById("contentFR");
                    var newFrame = document.createElement( "frame" );
                    // Copy all attributes over
                    var i = 0, attr;
                    for ( ; i < frame.attributes.length; i++ ) {
                        attr = frame.attributes[i];
                        // If we found a scrolling attribute, set it to 'no'
                        if ( attr.name === "scrolling" ) attr.value = "no";
                        // Apply old attribute to new frame
                        newFrame.setAttribute( attr.name, attr.value );
                    }
                    // Replace old frame with new frame
                    frame.parentElement.replaceChild( newFrame, frame );
                    // Null-out our variables
                    frame = i = attr = timer = null;
                }
            }, 10);
        </script>
    </head>
    <frameset cols="50%, *">
        <frame src="side.html">
        <frame src="page.html" id="contentFR" scrolling="Auto" noresize marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0">
    </frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you so much

Comment: Happy to have been of assistance, @fabulous. If this response answered your question, please consider accepting it for the benefit of others.